# Ansible uses wrong host settings

Tags: ansible

Considering the following hosts file:

```
[initial]
74.125.224.72 ansible_user=root

[default]
74.125.224.72 ansible_user=deploy ansible_port=2222
```

I have one playbook called *initial.yml* with `hosts: initial` and another called *site.yml* with `hosts: default`.

The problem is that if I run `ansible-playbook initial.yml`, it fails while trying to login as user deploy on port 2222. Shouldn't it just login as user root on port 22?

The contents of *initial.yml* (commenting out the roles makes no difference either):

```
---
- hosts: initial
  roles:
    - { role: common, tags: common }
    - { role: login, tags: login }
```

The contents of `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts.ini
roles_path = ./.tmp
retry_files_enabled = False
```

**Environment:**

- Ansible 2.3.1.0
- Python 2.7.13
- Ubuntu 17.04

Files under `/etc/ansible/` or `/etc/ssh/` have not been modified.

**EDIT:** I have been able to workaround this issue by using a different *hosts* file for *initial.yml*, and specifying it with `ansible-playbook --inventory-file=initial.ini`.

Comment: can you try this `ansible-playbook initial.yml -u root` just for testing and also try to remane `default` group to something else

Comment: @ArbabNazar I followed your instructions, and with `-vvv` it shows that it is still trying to connect as *deploy*!

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Even after you rename the `default` group to something else?

Comment: @freginold Yes! I had tried that before asking the question, and just tried again!

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Can you post your `initial.yml` file?

Comment: @freginold Included now in the question!

Comment: @TeresaeJunior What version of Ansible are you running?

Comment: @freginold Ansible 2.3.1.0, Python 2.7.13, Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Are there any entries in `~/.ssh/config` for this machine?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Does swapping the two host groups make a difference? (Putting `[default]` first, then `[initial]`)

Comment: @freginold There is no `.ssh/config`, and switching the order makes no difference. The only thing that worked so far was removing `74.125.224.72 ansible_user=deploy ansible_port=2222` completely.

Comment: @freginold Switching them works if I explicitly set `ansible_port=22` too, but simply specifying ansible_port and not switching them doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that with Ansible, defining the same host twice in the same file causes the second definition to override the first.  From the [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

> Within any section, redefining a var will overwrite the previous instance. If multiple groups have the same variable, the last one loaded wins. If you define a variable twice in a play’s vars: section, the 2nd one wins.

You'll have to work around that somehow, by using multiple host files, specifying the host from the command line, or using your workaround that you mentioned.  Another option that may work is to change `hash_behavior`:

> the previous describes the default config `hash_behavior=replace`, switch to ‘merge’ to only partially overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ansible-playbook initial.yml -i <your host file> -l initial
```

Here `-i` denotes your inventory file and `-l` for limiting playbook to a group.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference!

Comment: do your machine  has SSH access for this user on the target machine??

Comment: The roles included in *initial.yml* setup access for deploy and change the port to 2222. I can SSH to the machine with Ansible with `--ask-pass`, but the play fails because Ansible tries to connect as deploy on port 2222.

Comment: check this ```cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config``` file and make sure your are same sets of authorized_keys which you are using for port 22

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the system default, and there are no SSH keys yet (*initial.yml* sets them up).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154174/discussion-between-atul-agrawal-and-teresa-e-junior).

Comment: There is no `/etc/sshd_config`.

Comment: It would be inside ```/etc/ssh/``` folder with the name of ```sshd_config```.You need to have sudo access to view this file